# File empty when downloaded using SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net

I am using SSH.NET to download file from the SFTP and here is my code:

```
string host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPDomain"];
string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPUser"];
string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPPass"];
string remoteFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SFTPFileName"].ToString();

using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
{
    sftp.Connect();

    using (var file = File.OpenWrite(FilePath))
    {
        sftp.DownloadFile(remoteFileName, file);
    }

    sftp.Disconnect();
}
```

The problem is that the file which is csv is downloaded but it does not have any data inside. I changed the remoteFile path as well but still the file is downloaded with null data inside. I tried to check if file exists using

```
if (sftp.Exists(remoteFileName))
{
}
```

It always return true even if I change the remoteFileName with `"pp"`.

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong? Or recommend me another other library to download file from SFTP server. I have tried WinSCP but I am getting hostkey error so I tried to pass correct `SshHostKeyFingerprint` as guided by the server [tutorial](http://brickftp.com/ssh-keys-windows). Still I get the hostkey error. Is there any simple library i just need to download file from the SFTP?

Comment: already trying sshnet

Comment: check https://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/358307

Comment: Regarding WinSCP host key problem: The tutorial you link to is about your account private key, not about server's (host) key. See WinSCP article on [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint for use with scripting or .NET assembly?](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_hostkey). Note that SShNet default behavior to accept any host key is not secure. With SshNet, you should handle `HostKeyReceived` event and verify the host key. Key verification is enforced by WinSCP to upkeep security.

Comment: Did you try to debug the download (as SshNet is open source)? Do you have server-side logs? What is the server (software) you are connecting to?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen the same issue. Using SSH.NET's `ScpClient` instead of `SftpClient` worked for me. It's a drop-in replacement:

```
using (ScpClient client = new ScpClient(host, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();

    using (Stream localFile = File.Create(localFilePath))
    {
         client.Download(remoteFilePath, localFile);
    }
}
```

With ScpClient you only get upload/download functionality instead of the many additional features of SFTP, but this may be good enough for your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(FilePath))
{
    sftp.DownloadFile(remoteFileName, file);
}
```

You need to read the stream from the remote server before saving locally.

Comment: Kudos for a solution rather than a circumvention.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but thought I would put an answer here to save some effort for rookies like me who may encounter similar issue and just search up this question:

Essentially after you call the DownloadFile method and write into the stream, you have to reset the stream position back to beginning:

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
{
    sftp.Connect();

    using (var file = File.OpenWrite(FilePath))
    {
        sftp.DownloadFile(remoteFileName, file);
        file.Position = 0;
    }
```